# UML-how to make it the right model?

Tags: uml

I need to make an UML-diagram, but I am not sure on how to realize 1 specific thing int it. Let's say I have a `license` as object, which can either be an `terminal` or an `anywhere license`. It has to be one of them and cannot be none of it. I thought to have the `license` object which is connected to `anywhere license` and `terminal` with the cardinalities 0..1 to both. Is this right? Should I have other cardinalities or a completely other structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds more like a generalization, where `license` is an abstract class and `terminal` and `anywhere license` are its specializations.

However you might have wanted to just have in the `license` a `location` attribute with values `terminal` and `anywhere license` as possible values. Then create enumeration `LocationEnum` with available values `terminal` and `anywhere license`. Then add to `license' attribute:

```
location:LocationEnum
```

Then your `location` will have to have one of values available in `LocationEnum`.

Your question can also be understood in other ways but those are the most probable methods that will be a suitable solution. Which one to choose depends on more model details.

Comment: is there a way to do it without any attributes on `license`?

Comment: First solution (using generalization) uses no attributes. As the requirements are not 100% clear I tried to provide most reasonable solutions. But as I wrote the best solution will depend on the rest of the model.